# Retrieve many live stock quotes to one CSV file using Python

Tags: python

This code correctly prints all four live stock quotes from Interactive Brokers using ib_insync. Stock is an imported function within ib_insync.

```
stocks = ['SPY','ANGL','GDX','TMV']

test = list()
for stock in stocks:
    stock = Stock(stock, 'SMART','USD')
    contract = ib.qualifyContracts(stock)
    test.append(ib.reqMktData(contract[0],snapshot=True))
    ib.sleep(1)
for stock in test:
    print(stock.last)
```

This code below will only print the last quote in the list, in this case TMV. I believe this is because the 'w' is overwriting the entire file every time the loop is run? Or is the loop not setup correctly.

```
import csv
from ib_insync import *
stocks = ['SPY','ANGL','GDX','TMV']

stocks = ['SPY', 'TVIX']
while True:
test = list()

    for stock in stocks:
        stock = Stock(stock, 'SMART','USD')
        contract = ib.qualifyContracts(stock)
        test.append(ib.reqMktData(contract[0],snapshot=True))
        ib.sleep(15)

    for stock in test:
        f = open('spy-price.csv','w')
        f.write(str(stock.last))
        f.close()
```

How would I get the quotes to be setup so all four quotes are in the same file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Hopefully someone can verify my loop is setup correctly as I have heard I may have to increment this instead of using the for stock in stocks. But yeah I will try using 'a' and 'ab' instead of 'w'.

Comment: The simplest way is to open the file only once and close it after you're done.

Comment: And use the [open statement](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python)

Comment: @molbdnilo You are probably right. I am assuming I have to move f = open('stocks.csv','w') to above the while True

Answer (score 0):

use `f = open('spy-price.csv','w+')` to append to file
`w` = write
`w+` = append